# Integrating $ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{1 - 2u\cos(t)+u^2}$ using complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I want to integrate
$$ \int_0^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{1 - 2u\cos(t)+u^2}$$
for some $u \in \mathbb{C}$ with $|u| \neq 1$. I am supposed to do this by integrating $z \mapsto (z-u)^{-1}(z-u^{-1})^{-1}$ over a suitable circle. I truly have no idea how to approach this problem. Multiplying out, we have
$$ \frac{1}{z-u} \cdot \frac{1}{z-u^{-1}} = \frac{1}{z^2 - uz - u^{-1}z + uu^{-1}} = \frac{1}{1 + (-u - u^{-1})z + z^2},$$
but it is unclear to me how to choose a path of integration that makes this expression look even close to the one above. I think I might be missing some trig identity here.

Comment: The $z$ in the second expression should be the $u$ in the first. Integrate along $|u|=1$. Take into account that for such $u$ you have that $u^{-1}=\overline{u}$ and that $u+\overline{u}$ is equal to twice the real part of $u$, which is the cosine of the argument of $u$.

Comment: I'll try that! I wonder if why the question was phrased this way.

Comment: OK, so for $z$ on the unit circle, we have $-z-z^{-1} = -z - \overline{z} = -2\Re(z) = -2\cos(\arg z)$, thus $\int_{0}^{2\pi} \frac{dt}{1-2u\cos(t)+u^2} = \int_{\gamma} \frac{dz}{1 - 2\cos(\arg z) + u^2}dz = \int_{\gamma} (u-z)^{-1}(u-z^{-1})^{-1} dz$ for $\gamma$ the positively oriented unit circle, since $\arg z$ walks through $[0, 2\pi]$ on that path. I'm still unclear on how to evaluate the latter integral though

Comment: You could use [Cauchy integral formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula)

Comment: OK, so for $|u| > 1$, I should get $0$, and for $|u| < 1$ I should get $2\pi i$, right? I tried using homotopy for this.

Comment: I can't edit my comment anymore, but I think it should be $2\pi u$.

Answer (score 1):

An idea for you: change of variables:

$$z=e^{it}\implies dz=iz\,dt\implies dt=\frac{dz}{iz}\,,\,\,\text{and thus}\;\;\cos t=\frac{z+z^{-1}}2=\frac{z^2+1}{2z}$$

and

$$\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{dt}{1-2u\cos t+u^2}=\oint_{S^1:={|z|=1}}\frac{dz}{iz}\cdot\frac1{1-2u\frac{z^2+1}{2z}+u^2}=$$

$$=\frac1i\oint_{S^1}\frac{dz}{z-uz^2-u+u^2z}=i\oint_{S^1}\frac{dz}{uz^2-(u^2+1)z+u}=$$

$$=\frac i{u}\oint_{S^1}\frac{dz}{(z-u)\left(z-\frac1u\right)}\;,\;\;\text{(assuming, of course, }\;\;u\neq0)...$$

and there you go...